# In Rails, gsub works differently locally versus on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I ran the following code locally, where `:query` is `"new york"` and `excerpt` string contained `"New York"`:

```
<%= excerpt.gsub(params[:query].to_s, '<strong><span style="background-color: yellow">\0</span></strong>').html_safe %>
```

Then `gsub` matched `"New York"`. In other words, the `gsub` was case-insensitive. However, on Heroku, the match only took place if it matched exactly, i.e. `"new york"` is not assimilated with `"New York"`.

I changed the code above code to:

```
<%= excerpt.gsub(/#{params[:query].to_s}/i, '<strong><span style="background-color: yellow">\0</span></strong>').html_safe %>
```

and now it's working both locally and on Heroku.

Previously I've run into differences between localhost and a Heroku deployment due to the database format: I use SQLite locally and Postgres on Heroku, where the case sensitivity rules are different for queries. But as this is just performing a gsub on a string variable, I can't figure out why the local instance would find a match when the server one wouldn't. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Is `:query` really `"new york"`? Do you rather mean `params[:query]` is `"new york"`?

Comment: Can you please clarify the difference? I'm not sure what the distinction between those two is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass a string to `gsub` as the first argument, it will only match that exact string. There is no notion of case insensitive match for a string. The behavior on Heroku is the right behavior. It is rather your local environment that is somehow messed up.

Comment: I have just tried to replicate the behavior I described above (by switching back to my original code snippet), and now I am unable to do so. (Even locally, I'm not able to match case-insensitively using my original code now.) I'm quite confused, but I can only conclude I must have made a mistake. My apologies.